# Norm of an operator of $B(H,K)$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, c-star-algebras

Let H and K be Hilbert spaces.

> Let $T: H \to K$ be a bounded operator. Is it true that $\|T\|^3= \|TT^{\ast}T\|$

I think it should be true but I can’t see the proof of this. Any hints or ideas?

Comment: How do you define the product $T^3$ ? It cannot be composition

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг : Fixed,thanks

Comment: The last inequality is (trivially) true by submultiplicativity of norm and $\|T^*\|=\|T\|$

Comment: In the context of this question I suppose that $T^*:K\to H$ is the Hilbert-space adjoint operator.

Comment: @daw: that’s right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\|TT^*T\|^2 = \|(TT^*T)(TT^*T)^*\| = \|(TT^*)^3\| = \|TT^*\|^3 = \|T\|^6,
$$
where the second-to last inequality can be proven by the spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators.

Comment: The identity $\|T\|^2 = \|TT^*\|$ also holds if $T:H\to K$ with $K\ne H$.

Comment: I dint know that. Any references please?

Comment: it talks about only $B(H)$

Comment: The proofs for $B(H)$ carry over without much change to $B(H,K)$.

Comment: Ask a new question, if you like.

Comment: I’ll try it myself first thanks.