# Haagerup tensor product of $C^{\ast}$-algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^{\ast}$-algebras. Let $A \otimes^h B$ denotes the Haagerup tensor product Of $A$ and $B$. In [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/abs/maximal-cnorm-and-the-haagerup-norm/284ED80A766C068DD3097AFC1D96B7DE) paper it is given that for $x \in A \otimes B$,

> $\|x\|_h=\text{inf} \{\|\sum_{i=1}^na_ia_i^*\|^{1/2 }\|\sum_{i=1}^n b_i ^*b_i\| ^{1/2}, x= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \otimes b_i \in A \otimes B \}$

I know the definition of Haagerup tensor product for operator spaces but I don't see how does one obtains this beautiful expression of norm in case of $C^{\ast}$-algebras.

Comment: One adjoint is misplaced, it should be $b_i^\ast b_i$ instead. Moreover, do you already know a formula for the norm of the Haagerup tensor product or only its description in terms of the universal property?

Comment: @MaoWao: Edited, thanks. I know formula also for Haagerup norm given [here](https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/wittstock/OperatorSpace/node58.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E,F$ be operator spaces. As indicated in the comments, the Haagerup tensor product norm satisfies
$$
\|x\|_h=\inf\left\{\|a\|\|b\|: x=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}\otimes b_{j1}\right\}.
$$
Here $a\in M_{1,n}(E)$ and $b\in M_{n,1}(F)$. If $E\subset B(H)$ and $F\subset B(K)$, then $M_{1,n}(E)\subset B(H^n,H)$ and $M_{n,1}(F)\subset B(K,K^n)$ and we can use the $C^\ast$-identity for bounded operators to get
\begin{align*}
\|a\|^2&=\|a a^\ast\|=\|a_{11}a_{11}^\ast+\dots+a_{1n}a_{1n}^\ast\|,\\
\|b\|^2&=\|b^\ast b\|=\|b_{11}^\ast b_{11}+\dots+b_{n1}^\ast b_{n1}\|.
\end{align*}
Thus
$$
\|x\|_h=\inf\left\{\left\lVert\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j} a_{1j}^\ast\right\rVert^{1/2}\left\lVert\sum_{j=1}^n b_{j1}^\ast b_{j1}\right\rVert^{1/2}:x=\sum_j a_{1j}\otimes b_{j1}\right\}
$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much. First adjoint is misplaced? Can you also give a reference how one shows that max norm is dominated by Haagerup norm?

Comment: @MathLover You are righ about the adjoint, I corrected it. To the second question: No, sorry.

Comment: Do we get similar similar expression for Haagerup norm on $B(H,K)\otimes B(H,K)$ using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403824/norm-of-an-operator-of-bh-k) ? Apologies for troubling you!

Comment: Yes, that works exacly the same way.

Comment: Do we get power $1/3$ instead of $1/2$? Do you mind adding one or two lines?

Comment: No, everything stays the same. The only fact I use is that $a\in M_{k,l}(E)$ satisfies $\|a^\ast a\|=\|aa^\ast\|=\|a^2\|$, and this is true for $E=B(H,K)$, too.

Comment: Yes, you’re right. Probably we won’t get similar kind of expression if we go to bigger category of ternary rings of operators(norm closed  sub spaces of B(H,K),  closed under ternary operation $(x,y,z) \to xy^*z$) instead of category of $C^{\ast}$-algebras?

Comment: This property holds whenever $E$ and $F$ are completely isometrically embedded into $B(H)$ and $B(K)$, respectively, as stated in my answer. In the case of ternary rings of operators $E,F\subset B(H,K)$, they embed isometrically into $B(H\oplus K)$ by $x\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\x&0\end{pmatrix}$. So this formula still holds as long as you consider the operator space structure coming from the inclusion $E,F\subset B(H,K)$ (of course, the Hilbert spaces $H$ and $K$ may be different for $E$ and $F$, that doesn't matter).

Comment: Although product in TROs is not defined but it’s quite surprising the norm is obtained using product of elements (in $C^{\ast}$-algebra).I was expecting there would be a ternary product in the expression of norm. There might be some other equivalent expression of Haagerup norm in terms of ternary product?